# Cannot remove default gateway from NIC

Tags: networking

On a Server 2008 R2 box one NIC is connected to the internet, one (just recently) to a private network.

I noticed that IE was taking a long time to connect, and sometimes failing without a refresh, so I checked NIC 2 via the UI - the default gateway is blank.

Ran IPCONFIG and it's showing a gateway IP address. Tried changing using NETSH (e.g. netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection 2" static 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0 none)

Ran both IPCONFIG and NETSH SHOW CONFIG and it's still returning an IP address for the default gateway - sigh!

Any ideas (other than anything that involves rebooting the server)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open command with admin privileges and run this command.

netsh winsock reset catalog

Comment: You forgot to explain what the problem is, what that command does, and how it fixes the problem.

Comment: Reset catalog requires a reboot (can't do that until the Saturday after next patch Tuesday) - any way of getting it to play until then?

Comment: Used reset catalog after installing monthly patches, but the default gateway just keeps reappearing. I have voted your answer up to remove the negative down vote